# Unable to find font file for an imported module while using webpack

Tags: webpack

I have a `React` app and am using `webpack` as the module bundler. I am using module `react-widgets` for some input fields. `react-widgets` ship with a default css `react-widgets.css` which I want to include in my component which I did using

```
require('react-widgets/dist/css/react-widgets.css')
```

Inside the css file, there are references to the font file which are present in the `fonts` folder under `react-widgets/dist`

When I run the app, I see error on the browser console:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "../fonts/rw-widgets.eot?v=4.1.0"
```

Below is my webpack loader configuration

```
module: {
loaders: [{
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  loader: 'babel',
  include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
  query: {
    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
  }
},
{ test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" },
{ test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }]
}
```

I am guessing the problem may be that `webpack` is looking for the font file relative to the location where the `webpack.config.js` file is located instead of looking at location relative to the css file.

Please let me know how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Hey brother @Varun Gupta, How did you resolve your that issue ?
I am facing the same issue. 
Got same error (Module not found) but files on correct path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same error in `react-widgets` and found that this regex:

**`/\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/`**

dodn't match with filename that webpack try to load:

**rw-widgets.eot?v=4.1.0** because of **?v=4.1.0** part.

so correct regex in my and your case:

```
/\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/
```

but it's not enough because there will be other errors so the final version that works **for me**:

```
{ 
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/, 
    loaders: ["file"] 
},
{ 
    test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, 
    loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" 
},
{ 
    test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, 
    loader: "file-loader" 
},
```

here is the link that explain same that I said: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-widgets-webpack

**ps:** don't forget `npm install file-loader` and `npm install url-loader`

Comment: Good to know and would probably be helpful in general with webpack errors related to module loaders. Thanks!